# File.Move Causing a TagetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, exception

I have a program that, after downloading some files, is moving them around the C drive. When I call file.move though, I get the following exceptions:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I know that this can happen when you don't actually have the directory but I do. It actually DOES move the files correctly, it just throws up an error. I can't find any information on this? Should I just try and catch this fake error or should I figure out what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Show inner exception. I assume you don't `Dispose` object that keeps file handler (i.e. `WebClient`).

Comment: Indeed this is what I was doing. It wasn't file.move at all. Thanks much!

Comment: @user1767270: TIE is a usually reflection-specific, whereas `File.Move` is a wrapper above respective Win32 routine. Show either the code sample, which causes exception, or inner exception.

Answer (score 1):

File.Move doesn't throw that type of exception. Or at least that is what the list of exceptions on MSDN says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx

So this may be caused by something else, please check the inner exception and investigate further.

Comment: This is not answer, just comment.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Well, a partial answer, because it's a partially documented question. I'm trying to point him in the right direction, and that is to stop looking at File.Move

Comment: You can do this by leaving comment.

Comment: Indeed it was not file.move at all. I had never though to look toward msdn to see if exceptions were even valid, great idea and something I will add to my arsenal

Answer (score 0):

See InnerException for this exception and you will know the reason.

Comment: This is not answer, just comment.

Comment: I figured out my issue it's not with file.move but with disposing of the client itself. How do I see the InnerException though? When the popup comes up with the error as I described above, that's all I see. Where do I go to see this? Thanks!